# Creating user WITH password in ubuntu from PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, sudo

I have this PHP code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);



if(!empty($_GET) && !empty($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['mem']) && !empty($_GET['id']) &&!empty($_GET['k'])) {
    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $mem = $_GET['mem'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $pass = $_GET['k'];
    $fullname=  escapeshellarg($user."-".$id);

    echo $user; 
    echo $mem;
    echo $id; 
    echo $pass;
    echo "<br/>";

    mkdir("/home/servers/".$fullname, 0, true);
    $outputuser = shell_exec("sudo useradd -d /home/$fullname $fullname");
    $outputpass = shell_exec('echo -e '.$pass.'\n'.$pass.'\n" | sudo passwd '.$fullname);

    echo $outputpass;

}


?>
```

the password isnt working right though. when i run it from the terminal i get

```
 Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

now surely theres a better way of doing this without exposing both useradd AND passwd to not needing passwords in sudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use double quotes in the `second shell_exec` otherwise PHP doesn't convert escaped characters to control characters.

Comment: right I see, but is there no way to do it without needing that passwd at all? (perhaps using the -p flag in useradd, but i have no idea how to handle the encryption)

Answer (score 1):

This won't be an answer, but really important warning. Your script may allow user to gain full access to your server, as he may input "../" as a `$fullname`. Passing user input as an argument without using [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) is a suicide.

Resolution to your problem may be creating some crontab task that would create users from database every defined period of time. This way your password won't be exposed.

Comment: I understand this, for a start this is an internal facing Web servers taking known values from an external facing web server, it has no end-user control. This at this point in time is also only a proof of concept type thing, I will add security measures as soon as I get the code working in its raw form.

Comment: You can add http user permission to use adduser command then, but this is dangerous.

Comment: what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Something like `http ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/useradd,/bin/mkdir,/bin/ln,/bin/chown,/bin/cp,/bin/sed` with `visudo`

Comment: `www-data` already has access to use `useradd` and `passwd` without needing a password on sudo, it is able to create the user but the password changing fails because the `passwd` returns an error on the `"echo -e ".$pass."\n".$pass."\n" | sudo passwd ".$fullname`

Comment: why dont u simply use `useradd -u ... -p ...` ?

Comment: nevermind i got it working, turns out with was a foolish mistake, the echo -e wasnt entirely encapsulated with double quotes so was running incorrectly. its working fine now.

Comment: i attemtped to use th -p flag but you cant just use plaintext it apparently requires encryption, and i couldnt get the encryption to work correctly so the password was never accepted.

Comment: @JamesTrotter use PHP `crypt()` function to encrypt it.